# How do I get a `Pipe` to the standard input/output/error in Swift?

Tags: swift, pipe, stdio, foundation

When using `Process` in Swift, if you do not specify the `.standardInput`, `.standardOutput`, or `.standardError` properties, the `Process` inherits the standard input/output/error of the caller, which can be quite useful. But let's say that, for example, I want to tell a `Process` to send its output to the inherited standard error. It seems to me I would want to do something like `process.standardOutput = ProcessInfo.processInfo.standardError`, but `ProcessInfo` has no `standardError` property. How am I supposed to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I find the answer to this immediately after posting this question.

The desired objects are `FileHandle.standardInput`, `FileHandle.standardOutput`, and `FileHandle.standardError`.